# How to include Tree and Master Detail in same page

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle Apex. I am trying to create a 3 column page with  3 regions for tree structure, master detail screen and customized buttons respectively. I was able to create Tree in one page and Master-Detail in different page. When I bring them into one page, tree is not displayed.

When I click on any node of tree I am redirected to master-detail page and data is shown. But I need to display Master-Detail in same page where my tree is present but in a new region instead of redirecting to new page.

SQL Query of tree:

```
    select case
              when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then
               0
              when level = 1 then
               1
              else
               -1
           end as status
          ,level
          ,name as title
          ,null as icon
          ,id as value
          ,null as tooltip
          ,'f?p='||:APP_ID||':'||4||':'||:APP_SESSION as link 
      from (
       select to_char(d.DEPARTMENT_ID) id
    ,to_char(null) parent_id
    ,d.DEPARTMENT_NAME name
    from DEPARTMENTS d
    union all
    select t.DEPARTMENT_ID || '_' || task_configuration_id
    ,to_char(t.DEPARTMENT_ID)
    ,t.TASK_NAME
    from TASK_CONFIGURATION t
       )
    start with parent_id is null
    connect by parent_id = prior id
```

The same query works when creating a tree as new page, but doesn't work when included in Master-Detail page(made 'NULL' as Link in select list). Am I missing any configuration! please help..
Also, any help on creating the 3rd column for including custom buttons region will be a great help.

Comment: You said, "the tree is not displayed." Do you mean you can't see the region at all or that you don't see any data in it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be the branch or leave
the answer = is leaf 5 or more 
           = is branch 5 or more
           this the answer might be
           when connect_by_isleaf = 5 then
           when connect_by_isbranch = 5 then
that might conclude my opininion or suggestion